# Using recursion to build various trees

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to produce a complete range of possible trees, based on a given number of total mass. All trees having a first layer of mass 1, and for all subsequent layers underneath they either maintain the previous layer's mass, or it is increased by 1. (Barring the stem for now.) I figured recursion would lead me to the light, however I seem to have some problems producing more then a thin branch of 1, all the way to the bottom.

After the first pass an error reads:

```
  File "test3.py", line 21, in <module>
    for perm in tree(56):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I'm not sure where it wants to iterate. I have very little experience with recursion, and only in Prolog. This is my program:

```
def tree(total):
    tree = [1]
    current = 1

    def build_up(total,current):
        if total == 1:
            tree.append(1)
            print(tree)
            return 1
        elif total <= 0:
            return 0
        else:
            for i in range(current,current+1):
                tree.append(i)
                current = i
                total -= i
                build_up(total,current)

    build_up(total-1,current)

for perm in tree(56):
    print(perm)
```

Comment: When quoting error messages, please indicate which line of your code it applies to.

Comment: Your immediate exception is caused by the fact that `tree` doens't return anything (which is the same as returning `None` in Python). So `for perm in tree(56)` fails, as `tree(56)` is `None`, which is not iterable. This is probably not the only problem with your code, but I honestly don't know what you're trying to do, so I can't really help with anything else.

Comment: Changing 'multitude' to 'complete range' probably isn't sufficient disambiguation to get you an answer -- perhaps a rough mock up of expected output would help clarify.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm voting to close as unclear what's being asked. Please post your expected output and clarify what you mean by "mass", "stem", "branch" and "layer".